# Any ideas why this facebook connect script is not working?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I want to attach this script to a custom facebook icon. I have this javascript:

```
var fbClicked = false;
FB.init({appId: 'Myappid', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
function thFBShortCut() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        fbClicked = true;
        if (response.session && response.perms && fbClicked) {
            window.location = 'http://www.mysite.com/facebookauth/?ref=/';
        }
    }, {perms:'email,publish_stream'});
}
function thFBLogin() {
    fbClicked = true;
    $('.popbox').fadeOut(); 
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if(response.session && response.status == 'connected' && fbClicked) {
            window.location = 'http://www.mysite.com/facebookauth/?ref=/';
        }
    });
}
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    if(response.session && fbClicked){
        window.location = 'http://www.mysite.com/facebookauth/?ref=/';
    }
});

</script>

my html:
<a id="facebookicon" onclick="thFBShortCut()"</a>
```

maby, it is possible to simplify wthis script somehow?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to load Facebook javascript SDK before FB.init();

add Facebook div for SDK after `<body>`

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

and javascript:

```
(function() {
  var e = document.createElement('script');
  e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
  e.async = true;
  document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
})();
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    var fbClicked = false;
    FB.init({appId: 'Myappid', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        if(response.session && fbClicked){
            window.location = 'http://www.mysite.com/facebookauth/?ref=/';
        }
    });
}
function thFBShortCut() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        fbClicked = true;
        if (response.session && response.perms && fbClicked) {
            window.location = 'http://www.mysite.com/facebookauth/?ref=/';
        }
    }, {perms:'email,publish_stream'});
}
function thFBLogin() {
    fbClicked = true;
    $('.popbox').fadeOut(); 
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if(response.session && response.status == 'connected' && fbClicked) {
            window.location = 'http://www.mysite.com/facebookauth/?ref=/';
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Mihai, where I should trigger the script? Actions like onclick, lets say my id is div="facebooklogo", how to enable this script on this icon?

Comment: like you said ``<a id="facebookicon" onclick="thFBShortCut()">Login</a>``

Comment: Mihai, as it is wordpress theme I added <div id="fb-root"></div> right after <body <?php body_class(); ?>>, but when I load my site I keep getting these error messages: document.getElementById("fb-root") is null and FB is not defined
[Break On This Error] FB.login(function(response) { . maybe you know where I should search for problem?